error while running hugging face models on kaggle notebook
I am using the Llama3 model from the huggingface library on a kaggle notebook and am facing this error on running the pipeline module
I have trimmed out a major chunk of the stack trace because otherwise posting the question was not allowed with all that code and no description.
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 17, in Llama_Chat(system_role, user_msg)
     12 def Llama_Chat(system_role,user_msg):
     13   messages = [
     14     {"role": "system", "content": system_role},
     15     {"role": "user", "content": user_msg},
     16   ]
---> 17   outputs = pipeline(
     18       messages,
     19       max_new_tokens=256,
     20       temperature = 0.1
     21 
     22   )
     24   reply=outputs[0]["generated_text"][-1]["content"]
     25   return reply

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py:169, in add_hook_to_module.<locals>.new_forward(module, *args, **kwargs)
    167         output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
    168 else:
--> 169     output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
    170 return module._hf_hook.post_forward(module, output)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py:603, in LlamaSdpaAttention.forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, position_ids, past_key_value, output_attentions, use_cache, cache_position, position_embeddings, **kwargs)
    599 # We dispatch to SDPA's Flash Attention or Efficient kernels via this `is_causal` if statement instead of an inline conditional assignment
    600 # in SDPA to support both torch.compile's dynamic shapes and full graph options. An inline conditional prevents dynamic shapes from compiling.
    601 is_causal = True if causal_mask is None and q_len > 1 else False
--> 603 attn_output = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(
    604     query_states,
    605     key_states,
    606     value_states,
    607     attn_mask=causal_mask,
    608     dropout_p=self.attention_dropout if self.training else 0.0,
    609     is_causal=is_causal,
    610 )
    612 attn_output = attn_output.transpose(1, 2).contiguous()
    613 attn_output = attn_output.view(bsz, q_len, -1)

RuntimeError: cutlassF: no kernel found to launch!

this is the error i am facing while running huggingface models using the transformers library in kaggle .. i have checked the versions of cuda , pytorch they are fine
ChatGpt ,Claude etc. are all suggesting the version mismatch , but i am making no progress

Try setting torch.backends.cuda.enable_mem_efficient_sdp(False) and torch.backends.cuda.enable_flash_sdp(False). Source

yea it worked ... i did try something like this before as well but that just nerfed the model .. this time it worked

Great. I'll post it as answer then so you can accept it.
As for why it may have nerfed your (transformers-based) model; both of the flags when set to true are supposed to make calculating the SDP more efficient, so it does make sense from an intuitive point of view. Do keep in mind that they look like they are beta features.

Try setting the following backends to False.
torch.backends.cuda.enable_mem_efficient_sdp(False)
torch.backends.cuda.enable_flash_sdp(False)

Source
